# Copy Files When New Files are added Windows

Tags: windows-server-2008

Will Windows Server 2008 copy the new files that are added to the directory by some program when the copy is in progress? I have to copy some 500Gb of data to a new directory from the server. This directory will be actively utilized by the users to add more files. I could expect 300 files being added after the copy commences.

Comment: Make a DFS replication ?

Comment: Take a back up. I'm guessing the normal copy will do that.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, no.

It's hard to tell whether you want the files to copy or not (although it sounds like you do).  If you do, I have a script I use:

```
:loop

robocopy /s /z \\servername\sharename e:\destinationdir /mt:4 /r:0

goto loop
```

It's ugly.  Also, you have to kill it when you're finished with it.  But it does what I need it to do, so there you are.

If you don't, a simple robocopy (the line in the middle) should do the trick.